# What are the general methods to solve an ODE of type $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$, if P and Q are first degree polynomials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the general methods to solve an ODE of type $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$, if $P$ and $Q$ are first degree polynomials, not necessarily homogenous?
The most used methods I know -other than testing if the equation is exact and finding integrator factor if not- and that always work are:
Using the substitutions $v = \displaystyle\frac{y}{x}$,
and $\left\{\begin{matrix}X = x+h \\ Y = y+k \end{matrix}\right. $.
Are there another methods?